# How to try/catch all exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm completing a UWP app started by someone else. The app crashes frequently and I always end up in **App.g.i.cs** at

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

where I then have to say "no, don't start the debugger" and close 2 windows.

Is there somewhere I could put a big try/catch so that I don't have to restart the app each time this happen? I can't find anything in `AppShell` or `App`.

Or do I have to put a try/catch in every single event handler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to avoid starting the new debugger and restarting the app each time when encountering unhandled exceptions, you can use [**Application.UnhandledException event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) and set the [**Handled**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.unhandledexceptioneventargs.handled.aspx) property of the event arguments to true like following:

```cs
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    this.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Exception);
    };
}
```

> The **UnhandledException** event is used to notify the app about exceptions encountered by the XAML framework or by the Windows Runtime in general that have not been handled by app code.
>
> Normally after the **UnhandledException** event is fired, the Windows Runtime terminates the app because the exception was unhandled. The app code has some control over this: if the **UnhandledException** event handler sets the [**Handled**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.unhandledexceptioneventargs.handled.aspx) property of the event arguments to **true**, then in most cases the app will not be terminated.

For more info, please see **Remarks** of [Application.UnhandledException event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) and the blog: [Strategies for Handling Errors in your Windows Store Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/10/16/strategies-for-handling-errors-in-your-windows-store-apps/).

Comment: Thank you so much!  Sounds exactly like what I need.

Comment: That won't actually help you find and fix your bugs though... It's a temporary band-aid at best.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know most you cant do what you are trying to do (big try catch block) and for all intents and purposes you shouldn't even consider that possibility.

First try to determine why the app is crashing, on what page, is it when you try to something specific, the same thing everytime and then you can try catch some of the methods on that particular page and determine what's causing the crash

Comment: I totally agree with you once in production, but during the development period it is really annoying as I am working through many issues to have to keep restarting the process since the debugger startup (at least on my computer) seems slower than 'regular' windows apps.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: VS debugger is a slow process xD but there isnt really anything you can do.. UWP work with async calls so there's no Start method that you can try catch to catch any error or exceptio during execution :/ Try to understand where the comes from.. Sorry i could be any more help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat the cause rather than the symptoms, you should enable first-chance exceptions in the debugger settings. Then the debugger should break at the source of the exception, rather than in the global handler. You can then address the root cause of the problems directly.

Shipping an app that has the global handler blindly set every exception as "handled" even when you don't know why it's failing is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try/catch in your main app to catch all exceptions.  Shown is an example using Xamarin Forms DisplayAlert:

```
            try
            {
                //throw new Exception("gone and done it");
                MyMainProgram();
                                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Whoops!", ex.Message, "ok");
                throw ex;
            }
```

You can test this by uncommenting the "throw new Exception".  Execution stops with an alert you must answer, then continues by throwing the exception to prevent executing corrupted code.

Comment: I'd personally never rethrow an exception like that. You'll completely lose track of the stacktrace. Either use `throw;` or wrap it inside a new exception.