# Async methods in unhandled exception handler in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm writing handler for Unhandled Exception event which we will dump an exception to a file and then send to a server for further analyze. For now it will just show that crash had happen. I subscribed to the event. In that method I called a function for handling errors. However, when I wrote in the method this code:

```
public async Task HandleException(Exception exception)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Exception occurred");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

and run it in debug mode the Visual Studio shows Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger. In the first place I thought it was the problem that I'm trying to show Message Box when the GUI thread is dying. I changed the function to:

```
public async Task HandleManagedException(Exception 
{ 
    await FileStorage.WriteToFileAsync("someFile.txt", exception.ToString());
}
```

where function FileStorage.WriteToFileAsync looks like:

```
public async Task WriteToFileAsync(string filename, string data)
{
    var file = await this.storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, data);
}
```

In debugger mode, when I put breakpoint on `await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file,data)` it stops there. After pressing continue button, the same window shows like in the previous code. It is running properly when it is called from XAML events. I've searched the google and StackOverflow for the async methods in unhandled exception handler, but there was nothing related to my problem.

My questions are: What it is the reason for that error? Is it possible to use async methods in the Unhandled exception handler?

**Update:**
  Thank you for answers so far. The second question I answered myself after close debugging the code. It turned out that it is possible and the function is working as intended.

Comment: Are you sure your code reads WriteToFileAsync("someFile., exception.ToString()); ??

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because I put a breakpoint on 'await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, data);', run debugger and it stopped there.

Comment: well as theres a quote missing - it would seem you have an issue there then

Comment: What is the error message that you see on the JIT dialog? don't uncheck the `User-unhandled` checkbox in the Exceptions dialog, it will hide it from you.

Comment: I get Warning "A debugger is attached to 'some file' but not configured to deubg this unhandled exception. To deubg this exception, detach the current debuger. In the dialog i mentioned there is message "An unhandled win32 exception occoured in .exe with error [6972]

Comment: Ahh yes, my favorite worst exception message ever ever....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger dialog, we can set [**UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.Handled**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.unhandledexceptioneventargs.handled.aspx) property to `true` like following:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
}

private async void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    await HandleException(e.Exception);
}

public async Task HandleException(Exception exception)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Exception occurred");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

In debug mode, you get the Warning and Just-In-Time Debugger dialog because there are following codes in ***App.g.i.cs***:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) 
        global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
#endif
```

These codes are generated automatically when we build the project. And from these codes, we can find while in debug model, if there is any unhandled exception, it will call [Debugger.Break Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx) and this will result in the Warning and Just-In-Time Debugger dialog.

Setting `e.Handled = true;` in our handler can avoid this. For more info, you can check this similar question: [How to try/catch all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607222/how-to-try-catch-all-exceptions). However, as you can see this will only happen in debug mode, in release model, your code should work well.

Comment: I think the question is why do we need to do this at all... Why doesn't this debug like WPF lol

Comment: I checked that property and it works. However I would prefer to quit the application after unhandled exception and not show that dialog. Is there other methods not to show that popup?

Comment: @MaxiKing I'm afraid there is no other way. These codes are generated automatically and used to help us to debug unhandled exception. Usually, when we encounter unhandled exception, Visual Studio will break in this method and we can get the exception information form `e` parameter. In this situation, we should stop debug and deal with this exception. And as I've said, this will only happen in debug mode, in release mode, the Windows Runtime will terminate your application after unhandled exception and there will be no dialog.